# How do I setup pyspark in VS Code?

Tags: pyspark, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run pypsark in VS-Code and I can't seem to point my environment to the correct pyspark driver and path. When I run pyspark in my terminal window it looks like this:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.1
      /_/

Using Python version 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020 11:26:31)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

When I run a file in in Vs-Code I get this error:

```
File "/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 477, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.8, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

In my bash_profile I think I have the setup correct:

```
export SPARK_PATH=~/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
alias snotebook='$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[2]'
```

I get that it's looking at two different versions so, what do I need to do to configure my environment correctly in VS code to run pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was solved by adding the following lines to
`<sparkHome>/conf/spark-env.sh`:

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.8
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3.8
```

AND
in vscode setting python interpreter to 3.8 too (you can set it from command palette and typing `Python:Select Interpreter`.

If you don't have spark-env.sh, make a copy of the template file already in the `conf` folder.